# Aligning text in the upper right corner in a table cell without CSS?

Tags: html, html-table

I have this table an I want to align the "up right" text in the upper right corner of that cell. Thing is, **I can't use CSS**. I have no idea how to achieve that. Is there a way at all using pure HTML?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <font>Something</font> 
            up right
         </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: [`<sup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup)?

Comment: Extending my own comment: is this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/dWvqL/ ?

Comment: sup just moves it up, but not right. I need to move it right as well. But its a good idea!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should solve your problem with no CSS

```
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <font>Something</font> 
                up right
             </td>
          <td valign="top" align="right">
                <font>Something</font> 
                up right
             </td>
         </tr>
    </table>
```

**Valign** : vertically aligns your content in the cell

**align**  : Horizontally aligns your content in the cell.

use this combo to give top right alignment

Check this demo out http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yfbJj

Comment: This does not quite do what the question asked for, as this breaks the cell into two cells. But the approach could be modified so that there content is in one cell – but within an inner table.